# XPath within OOXML

Tags: xml, xpath, openxml

Here's an XPath / OOXML question for you gurus.

I have a MSOffice docx with highlighted text of different colours that I have to convert to XML, and then identify using XPath where all those highlights are, regardless of the colour, so that they can be filtered in an XML rule.

Here's how an example looks in MSWord

[image]

I understand how I can select the child node  if it exists using //w:p/w:r/w:rPr/w:highlight[@w:val='yellow']"
but not how I can select the actual `W:t` node containing the text if a highlight node exists in the same `<w:r>` block.

Example:  I need to select the text within `<W:t>` if a `<w:highlight>` exists within the parent  node and do this for all cases within the document.

So in this example I need to select the text "This one goes because it is highlighted yellow" because it has a w:highlight node with a w:val of yellow related to it.

```
<w:r w:rsidRPr="003815B4">
                        <w:rPr>
                            <w:highlight w:val="yellow"/>
                        </w:rPr>
                        <w:t>This one goes because it is highlighted yellow</w:t>
                    </w:r>
```

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated :-)

Here's an xml example of the docx ( with the OOXML headers removed for readability)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<doc>
<w:body>
                <w:p w:rsidR="00B93038" w:rsidRDefault="003815B4">
                    <w:r>
                        <w:t>This line stays because it is not highlighted in any colour</w:t>
                    </w:r>
                </w:p>
                <w:p w:rsidR="003815B4" w:rsidRDefault="003815B4">
                    <w:r w:rsidRPr="003815B4">
                        <w:rPr>
                            <w:highlight w:val="yellow"/>
                        </w:rPr>
                        <w:t>This one goes because it is highlighted yellow</w:t>
                    </w:r>
                </w:p>
                <w:tbl>
                    <w:tblPr>
                        <w:tblStyle w:val="TableGrid"/>
                        <w:tblW w:w="0" w:type="auto"/>
                        <w:tblLook w:val="04A0" w:firstRow="1" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="0" w:noHBand="0" w:noVBand="1"/>
                    </w:tblPr>
                    <w:tblGrid>
                        <w:gridCol w:w="4621"/>
                        <w:gridCol w:w="4621"/>
                    </w:tblGrid>
                    <w:tr w:rsidR="003815B4" w:rsidTr="003815B4">
                        <w:tc>
                            <w:tcPr>
                                <w:tcW w:w="4621" w:type="dxa"/>
                            </w:tcPr>
                            <w:p w:rsidR="003815B4" w:rsidRDefault="003815B4">
                                <w:r>
                                    <w:t>And so on</w:t>
                                </w:r>
                            </w:p>
                        </w:tc>
                        <w:tc>
                            <w:tcPr>
                                <w:tcW w:w="4621" w:type="dxa"/>
                            </w:tcPr>
                            <w:p w:rsidR="003815B4" w:rsidRDefault="003815B4">
                                <w:r w:rsidRPr="003815B4">
                                    <w:rPr>
                                        <w:highlight w:val="cyan"/>
                                    </w:rPr>
                                    <w:t>Blue highlight</w:t>
                                </w:r>
                            </w:p>
                        </w:tc>
                    </w:tr>
                    <w:tr w:rsidR="003815B4" w:rsidTr="003815B4">
                        <w:tc>
                            <w:tcPr>
                                <w:tcW w:w="4621" w:type="dxa"/>
                            </w:tcPr>
                            <w:p w:rsidR="003815B4" w:rsidRDefault="003815B4">
                                <w:r>
                                    <w:t>Red</w:t>
                                </w:r>
                            </w:p>
                        </w:tc>
                        <w:tc>
                            <w:tcPr>
                                <w:tcW w:w="4621" w:type="dxa"/>
                            </w:tcPr>
                            <w:p w:rsidR="003815B4" w:rsidRDefault="003815B4">
                                <w:r>
                                    <w:t xml:space="preserve">Mixed </w:t>
                                </w:r>
                                <w:r w:rsidRPr="003815B4">
                                    <w:rPr>
                                        <w:highlight w:val="red"/>
                                    </w:rPr>
                                    <w:t>text</w:t>
                                </w:r>
                                <w:r>
                                    <w:t xml:space="preserve"> with </w:t>
                                </w:r>
                                <w:r w:rsidRPr="003815B4">
                                    <w:rPr>
                                        <w:highlight w:val="green"/>
                                    </w:rPr>
                                    <w:t>some highlighted</w:t>
                                </w:r>
                                <w:r>
                                    <w:t xml:space="preserve"> and some not</w:t>
                                </w:r>
                            </w:p>
                        </w:tc>
                    </w:tr>
                    <w:tr w:rsidR="003815B4" w:rsidTr="003815B4">
                        <w:tc>
                            <w:tcPr>
                                <w:tcW w:w="4621" w:type="dxa"/>
                            </w:tcPr>
                            <w:p w:rsidR="003815B4" w:rsidRDefault="003815B4"/>
                        </w:tc>
                        <w:tc>
                            <w:tcPr>
                                <w:tcW w:w="4621" w:type="dxa"/>
                            </w:tcPr>
                            <w:p w:rsidR="003815B4" w:rsidRDefault="003815B4"/>
                        </w:tc>
                    </w:tr>
                </w:tbl>
                <w:p w:rsidR="003815B4" w:rsidRDefault="003815B4"/>
                <w:p w:rsidR="003815B4" w:rsidRDefault="003815B4">
                    <w:r>
                        <w:t>Another highlight</w:t>
                    </w:r>
                </w:p>
                <w:p w:rsidR="003815B4" w:rsidRDefault="003815B4">
                    <w:r>
                        <w:t>Some text</w:t>
                    </w:r>
                </w:p>
                <w:p w:rsidR="003815B4" w:rsidRDefault="003815B4"/>
                <w:p w:rsidR="003815B4" w:rsidRDefault="003815B4">
                    <w:r>
                        <w:t>End</w:t>
                    </w:r>
                    <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
                    <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
                </w:p>
                <w:sectPr w:rsidR="003815B4">
                    <w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838"/>
                    <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="708" w:footer="708" w:gutter="0"/>
                    <w:cols w:space="708"/>
                    <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
                </w:sectPr>
            </w:body>
</doc>
```

Comment: What environment do you use XPath in?

Comment: Did you try //w:p/w:r/w:t[../w:rPr/w:highlight/@w:val='yellow']

Comment: Mathias hi, it's Java and Sax Parser.

Comment: Jason - I think you have the answer - am not in front of my workstation until tomorrow morning but just looking at it it seems the solution!. Forgot about levels../

Comment: I think this will work but I have namespace issues to resolve

Comment: Jason would you turn your suggestion into an answer so I can accept it?  You helped solve my issue, very many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this should work. 
Initialize a variable with the namespace:

```
w = 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'
```

Since you haven't mentioned the language you are using , I'll just specify the xpath syntax below:
This code just extracts text with general highlight.

```
 './/w:p/w:r/w:highlight/../..//w:t', namespaces = {'w':w}
```

To specify value say yellow, use:
`'.//w:p/w:r/w:highlight[@w:val="yellow"]/../..//w:t', namespaces = {'w':w}`
Note that the "w" is case sensitive , do not use upper case letters.

As for the `'../..//'` , if u check the xml , the highlight property comes under the rPr tag which is one level below `w:r`. So a `../` selects parent(i.e w:rPr) followed by another `../` to select the grandparent(i.e w:r) and then another `/` selects the text under the `w:r` .

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your input.  I have actually solved my problem with the suggestion from Jason above but he has not made his comment into a question so I cannot select it.

Comment: Your approach would work too, but I cannot declare variables within the very restrictive schemarules / ruleset of this software I have to use. It will not even accept namespaces with a prefix so by declaring w as the new root element in the openxml doc I can get the parser to work in this Java software.  If Jason does not respond I would be happy to accept your answer

Comment: Ohk,  mine was a more pythonic answer.  You could consider using local-name()  instead. That wouldn't require the namespaces argument then..

Comment: Thanks I tried that too! Just about lost the plot over this issue but thankfully all working. Thank you once again for your input :-)